# Angular updates on asset file change

Tags: angular, angular-cli, assets

I have a angular4 project where I constantly read json file that is in assets. I am writing single page application. But thing is that when I update that file(that is in assets) my web page instantly restarts. Is it possible to omit page from restarting on json file change(file is changed and after that saved manually)?

Comment: Generally yes, but _how_ depends on information not provided (your tool chain)

Comment: @LoverKiss are you using the Angular CLI?

Comment: @cgatian yes, I am

Answer (score 0):

The Angular CLI uses the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) under the hood to perform the asset copy. There currently is no configuration setting you can enable [through the CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) or the plugin to disable file watching on copy.

My best advice is to create a script specifically to copy the file into the `dist` folder. Run this script while in dev mode on `npm start` along side the `ng serve` command.